# Why doesn't Hotspot JIT optimize-out code that has no external effects?

Tags: jit, jvm-hotspot

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getTheAnswer();
    }

    static int getTheAnswer() {
        int s = 0;
        for (int i = 3; i < 10; i++) {
            s += i;
        }
        return s;
    }
  }
```

Could be optimized to a no-op. It doesn't produce anything.

Comment: Why do you think it is not optimized out?